# What is the correct way to declare a pointer to a __far pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

On an embedded target I use far pointers to access some parts of the memory map.

near pointer (without explicitely specifying __near):

```
unsigned int *VariableOnePtr;
```

Pointer to near pointer:

```
unsigned int **VariableOnePtrPtr;
```

far pointer:

```
unsigned int *__far VariableTwoPtr;
```

What is the correct way to declare a pointer to a far pointer? Does this pointer have to be a far pointer itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you would do this:

```
unsigned int * __far *VariableThreePtrPtr;
```

A far pointer to a far pointer would be:

```
unsigned int * __far * __far VariableFourPtrPtr;
```

Answer (score 3):

"__far" is a proprietary, non-standard extension of your platform, so there can't exist any generic way to use it. See the compiler and standard library manufaturer's manuals for how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use typedefs for that, for example

```
typedef unsigned int *__far VariableTwoPtr_t;
VariableTwoPtr_t* VariableTwoPtrPtr;
```